# Why is a small wrapped method not getting optimised?

Tags: java

I am running an experiment to determine the performance overhead of wrapping a method. I have read that the JIT compiler and/or JVM optimise small methods, but I seem to consistently incur a 3-5% performance penalty.

The code is as follows:

```
import java.util.* ;

public class WrappingTest1{
    private WrappingTest1(){
        // Empty.
    }

    private static void findPrimes(
        final Long maxValue ,
        final List< Long > foundPrimes
    ){
        if(
            maxValue > 2L
        ){
            Boolean isPrime ;
            foundPrimes.clear() ;

            for(
                Long i = 2L ;
                i <= maxValue ;
                i += 1L
            ){
                isPrime = true ;
                for(
                    Long j = 2L ;
                    j < i ;
                    j += 1L
                ){
                    if(
                        ( i % j ) == 0
                    ){
                        isPrime = false ;
                    }
                }
                if(
                    isPrime
                ){
                    foundPrimes.add(
                        i
                    ) ;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static void wrapper(
        final Long input ,
        final List< Long > output
    ){
        findPrimes(
            input ,
            output
        ) ;
    }

    public static void main(
        final String[] args
    ){
        ArrayList< Long > primes ;
        Long startTime ;
        Long endTime ;
        Double duration ;
        Double meanDuration ;
        Long primeRange ;
        Long warmupIterations ;
        Long benchmarkIterations ;

        primes = new ArrayList<>() ;
        meanDuration = 0.0 ;
        primeRange = 100L ;
        warmupIterations = 20000L ;
        benchmarkIterations = 100000L ;

        System.out.println(
            "Experiment started."
        ) ;

        // Unwrapped warmup.
        for(
            Long i = 0L ;
            i < warmupIterations ;
            i += 1L
        ){
            findPrimes(
                primeRange ,
                primes
            ) ;
        }

        // Unwrapped benchmark.
        startTime = System.nanoTime() ;
        for(
            Long i = 0L ;
            i < benchmarkIterations ;
            i += 1L
        ){
            findPrimes(
                primeRange ,
                primes
            ) ;
        }
        endTime = System.nanoTime() ;
        duration = ( endTime.doubleValue() - startTime.doubleValue() ) / 1E9 ;
        System.out.println(
            "Unwrapped runtime: " + duration + " seconds."
        ) ;

        // Wrapped warmup.
        for(
            Long i = 0L ;
            i < warmupIterations ;
            i += 1L
        ){
            wrapper(
                primeRange ,
                primes
            ) ;
        }

        // Wrapped benchmark.
        startTime = System.nanoTime() ;
        for(
            Long i = 0L ;
            i < benchmarkIterations ;
            i += 1L
        ){
            wrapper(
                primeRange ,
                primes
            ) ;
        }
        endTime = System.nanoTime() ;
        duration = ( endTime.doubleValue() - startTime.doubleValue() ) / 1E9 ;
        System.out.println(
            "Wrapped runtime: " + duration + " seconds."
        ) ;

        System.out.println(
            "Experiment completed."
        ) ;
    }
}
```

The results are as follows:

```
Experiment started.
Unwrapped runtime: 4.851473465 seconds.
Wrapped runtime: 5.078349508 seconds.
Experiment completed.
```

Why is this happening? How can I get the JVM to inline the wrapped method, or otherwise optimise it such that the wrapper is ignored?

Thanks.

Comment: Funny indentation!

Comment: @userunknown: thanks. It's not actually mine, it's how the scenario project was formatted. Since I built this benchmark in the same project, it got formatted the same way (Eclipse formatter), and I didn't see a pressing need to change it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the cause of the slowdown was not the optimisation (or lack thereof) of the wrapped/unwrapped method calls, but rather the lack of optimisation of the main method itself. Profiling with [-XX:-PrintCompilation](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html#DebuggingOptions) shows that the wrapped/unwrapped method calls are optimised after 10K warmup iterations, as per the default settings ([-XX:CompileThreshold=10000](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html#PerformanceTuning)). However, only after about 70K warmup iterations does the JVM profiling report that the main method is compiled. So, if the warmup iterations are less than 70K, the unwrapped runtime is significantly lower than the wrapped runtime; but if the warmup iterations are 70K and above, then the two runtimes are similar. Of course, this only applies to the specified benchmark - individual program will likely have different results.

Answer (score 0):

Optimistic, to chose `final Long maxValue` for iterations, but then use 100 as maxValue.

If you replace your Longs in the loops with ints, you might get a 10 times speedup.

A 2nd and 3rd, drastic improvement is, to loop until Math.sqrt (i) and only, if it isn't already proven to be not prime:

```
 for (int j = 2; j <= Math.sqrt(i) && isPrime; ++j)
```

I know, that you aren't behind an efficient prime finding algorithm, but it's all about microbenchmarking the wrapper, but the underlying lesson to learn is, that such assumptions are most of the time not the bottleneck of an application.

Beside from that, you should try your test in opposite direction, first wrapped, then unwrapped. To make such changes simple, you should factor out the loops and timings.

```
import java.util.* ;

public class WrappingTest1
{
    PrimeFinder[] pfs = new PrimeFinder[2];
    int primeRange = 1000;

    private WrappingTest1 ()
    {
        // pfs[1] = new UnwrappedFinder ();
        // pfs[0] = new WrappedFinder (pfs[1]);
        pfs[0] = new UnwrappedFinder ();
        pfs[1] = new WrappedFinder (pfs[0]);
    }

    void test ()
    {
        for (PrimeFinder pf: pfs)
            runblock (pf);
    }

    void loopy (int iterations, PrimeFinder pf, ArrayList <Integer> primes)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < iterations; ++i)
            pf.findPrimes (primeRange, primes);
    }

    void runblock (PrimeFinder pf)
    {
        int warmupIterations = 20000;
        int benchmarkIterations = 100000;
        ArrayList <Integer> primes = new ArrayList<Integer> (50000) ;

        // warmup.
        loopy (warmupIterations, pf, primes);
        // enchmark.
        Long startTime = System.nanoTime();
        loopy (benchmarkIterations, pf, primes);
        Long endTime = System.nanoTime() ;

        Double duration = (endTime.doubleValue () - startTime.doubleValue ()) / 1E9 ;
        System.out.printf ("%s runtime: %4.2f seconds.\n", pf.name(), duration);
        // had to make sure, that we're really producing valid primes:
        // and that they survive the code changes.
        for (int p: primes) {
            System.out.printf ("%d ", p);
        }
        System.out.println ("bye");
    }

    abstract class PrimeFinder {
        abstract void findPrimes (final int maxValue, final List <Integer> foundPrimes);
        abstract String name ();
    }

    class UnwrappedFinder extends PrimeFinder {
        String name () {return "Unwrapped";}
        void findPrimes (final int maxValue, final List <Integer> foundPrimes)
        {
            if (maxValue > 2)
            {
                foundPrimes.clear () ;
                for (int i = 2; i <= maxValue; ++i)
                {
                    Boolean isPrime = true;
                    for (int j = 2; j <= Math.sqrt(i) && isPrime; ++j)
                        if ((i % j) == 0)
                            isPrime = false;
                    if (isPrime)
                        foundPrimes.add (i);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    class WrappedFinder extends PrimeFinder {
        String name () {return "  Wrapped";}
        private PrimeFinder pf;
        public WrappedFinder (PrimeFinder ppf)
        {
            pf = ppf;
        }
        void findPrimes (final int input, final List <Integer> output) {
            pf.findPrimes (input, output);
        }
    }

    public static void main (final String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println ("Experiment started.");
        WrappingTest1 wt1 = new WrappingTest1 ();
        wt1.test ();
        System.out.println ("Experiment completed.") ;
    }
}
```

Running my code with PrimeRange = 100, but 1M iterations, I get:

```
Unwrapped runtime: 2,34 seconds.
Unwrapped runtime: 2,53 seconds.
Unwrapped runtime: 2,50 seconds.
Unwrapped runtime: 2,50 seconds.
Unwrapped runtime: 2,49 seconds.
Unwrapped runtime: 2,52 seconds.
Unwrapped runtime: 2,59 seconds.
Unwrapped runtime: 2,60 seconds.
Unwrapped runtime: 2,58 seconds.
Unwrapped runtime: 2,52 seconds.

  Wrapped runtime: 2,36 seconds.
  Wrapped runtime: 2,36 seconds.
  Wrapped runtime: 2,36 seconds.
  Wrapped runtime: 2,36 seconds.
  Wrapped runtime: 2,37 seconds.
  Wrapped runtime: 2,37 seconds.
  Wrapped runtime: 2,36 seconds.
  Wrapped runtime: 2,41 seconds.
  Wrapped runtime: 2,37 seconds.
  Wrapped runtime: 2,37 seconds.
```

So, surprisingly the wrapped version is faster. Hm. 
Changing the order in PrimeFinder[] pfs, they come much closer together, wrapped: 2.46, unwrapped 2.52.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

Moving from Longs to Integers helps reduce the time, but the unwrapped method is still significantly faster than the wrapped method.

Also, wrapping the prime finder(s) in abstraction slows it down compared to leaving it as a static method.

Comment: And changing the invocation order? Writing a for loop around the invocations (10x)?

Comment: Changing the invocation order results in a small change in the ratio between the runtimes, but the wrapped is still significantly slower than the unwrapped. However, if the warmup is run for long enough, the main method gets optimised, and that seems to result in the wrapped and unwrapped methods having similar runtime. A loop around the invocations can achieve that, but so can just running the warmup for 100K - 200K iterations.